# Create a table matrix for roles and permissions (read,write,delete,write special) using JSON (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want a create a Table matrix for roles and permissions(read, write, delete, write special) using Jquery from JSON data. The table should have check boxes for read, write, delete and write special. The roles and permissions mapping cell should have read, write, delete and write special permissions checked if the value is present in JSON.

"PermissiontypeID": 1 is for Read , 
"PermissiontypeID": 2 is for Write , 
"PermissiontypeID": 3 is for Delete ,
"PermissiontypeID": 4 is for Write Special .

This is my JSON format:

```
   var obj =[
  {
    "PermissionID": 1,
    "ProjectRoleID": 1,
    "ScreenID": 1,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 1",
    "PermissiontypeID": 1,
    "RoleName": "Role 1"
  },
 {  
    "PermissionID": 1,
    "ProjectRoleID": 2,
    "ScreenID": 1,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 1",
    "PermissiontypeID": 2,
    "RoleName": "Role 2"
  },
 {  
    "PermissionID": 2,
    "ProjectRoleID": 2,
    "ScreenID": 1,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 1",
    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
    "RoleName": "Role 2"
  },
  { 
    "PermissionID": 2,
    "ProjectRoleID": 2,
    "ScreenID": 2,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
    "PermissiontypeID": 1,
    "RoleName": "Role 2"
  },
  { 
    "PermissionID": 2,
    "ProjectRoleID": 2,
    "ScreenID": 2,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
    "PermissiontypeID": 2,
    "RoleName": "Role 2"
  },
 { 
    "PermissionID": 2,
    "ProjectRoleID": 2,
    "ScreenID": 2,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
    "RoleName": "Role 2"
  },
  {
    "PermissionID": 2,
    "ProjectRoleID": 3,
    "ScreenID": 2,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
    "RoleName": "Role 3"
  },
  {
    "PermissionID": 3,
    "ProjectRoleID": 3,
    "ScreenID": 3,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 3",
    "PermissiontypeID": 1,
    "RoleName": "Role 3"
  },
  {
    "PermissionID": 3,
    "ProjectRoleID": 3,
    "ScreenID": 3,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 3",
    "PermissiontypeID": 2,
    "RoleName": "Role 3"
  },
  {
    "PermissionID": 3,
    "ProjectRoleID": 3,
    "ScreenID": 3,
    "ScreenName": "Screen 3",
    "PermissiontypeID": 4,
    "RoleName": "Role 3"
  }
]
```

This is the table I want using Jquery:

[image]

This is the HTML I am expecting:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <th>Permission</th>
      <th>Role 1</th>
      <th>Role 2</th>
      <th>Role 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Screen 1
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Screen 2
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Screen 3
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            R
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            W
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            D
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            WS
            </label>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/581wLa1v/)

With the JSON change, it's much better and easyer
HTML

```
 <table id="perm">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>Permissions</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $table = $( "#perm" );
    var $tHead = $table.find( ".header" );
    var permissions = ['',"R", "W", "D", "WS" ]
    // Count and add Roles 
    var roles = [];
    var numRoles = 0;
    for( i in obj ) {
        if( roles[ obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID ] == undefined ) {
            roles[ obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID ] = obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID;
            numRoles++;
            $tHead.append( '<th colspan="4" class="role_' + obj[ i ].ProjectRoleID + '">' + obj[ i ].RoleName + '</th>' );
        }
    }
    // Load table
    for( i in obj ) {
        var element = obj[ i ];
        // Add screen row
        if( $table.find( "tr.row_" + element.ScreenID ).length == 0 ) {
            $table.append( '<tr class="row_' + element.ScreenID + '"><td>' + element.ScreenName + '</td></tr>' );
            $row = $table.find( '.row_' + element.ScreenID );
            for( j in roles ) {
                var role = roles[ j ];
                for( k = 1; k < 5; k++ ) {
                    var uniqueCheck = "check_" + element.ScreenID + "_" + role + "_" + k;
                    $row.append( '<td class="cell_' + role + '"><input id="' + uniqueCheck + '" name="' + uniqueCheck + '" type="checkbox"> ' + permissions[ k ] + ' </td>' );
                }
            }
        }
        var checkId = "#check_" + element.ScreenID + "_" + element.ProjectRoleID + "_" + element.PermissiontypeID;
        $( checkId ).attr( "checked", "checked" );
    }
});
```

All the checkbox have uniqueId and Name so created
"check_SCREENID_ROLEID_PERMISSIONTYPEID"

Comment: Hi @Riccardo C, Thanks For Your Reply. I have changed the JSON. And also added one more permission(write special), can you please help me on this.

Comment: Changed the reply. Much more "short" here. And the "roles" are "dynamically loaded", thus it will work if you add any new role. The only thing that isn't "dynamically" loaded are the "permissions". If you want to make them "dynamic" too, you have to add the "permission description" ("R", "W", "D", "WS") to the object

Comment: Thanks alot  @Riccardo C, this is exactily what I wanted. Now after changing the values if I have to save, How to get the response JSON ?

Comment: I think this is a completely different issue, that is a bit out of theme in this question. One of the approach you can apply, is simply put all the table inside a "form" tag, and send it to the server with POST; the server action will update the "source" of your JSON values (DB, files or whathever you use) and then load the same page. Another approach is using the jquery $.ajax() function to send the data to the server (that will update the values in the "source"), without reloading the page. Search on the web or here on stackoverflow about $.ajax or, if you find nothing, open a new question

Comment: Why + is added before name attribute <input id="' + uniqueCheck + '" + name="' + uniqueCheck + '" type="checkbox"> ' i think it can be removed

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, I'm removing it

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be:

```js
        $(function() {
            jQuery.each(obj, function(index, item) {
                var row = $('#perm tr td:first-child').filter('td:contains("' + item.ScreenName + '")');
                if (row.length == 0) {
                    $('#perm > tbody:last-child').append(rowTemplate.replace('{replace}', item.ScreenName));
                    row = $('#perm tr:last');
                } else {
                    row = row.parent();
                }

                var role = 1;
                switch (item.RoleName) {
                    case 'Role 1':
                        role = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'Role 2':
                        role = 3;
                        break;
                    case 'Role 3':
                        role = 4;
                        break;
                }
                switch (item.PermissiontypeID) {
                    case 1:
                        row.find('td:nth-child(' + role + ') :checkbox:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        row.find('td:nth-child(' + role + ') :checkbox:eq(1)').prop('checked', true);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        row.find('td:nth-child(' + role + ') :checkbox:eq(2)').prop('checked', true);
                        break;
                }
            });
        });

        // Initialization values
        var rowTemplate = '<tr>\
                              <td>\
                                  {replace}\
                              </td>\
                              <td>\
                                  <div class="checkbox">\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           R\
                                     </label>\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           W\
                                     </label>\
                                     <label>\
                                          <input type="checkbox">\
                                           D\
                                     </label>\
                                  </div>\
                               </td>\
                               <td>\
                                  <div class="checkbox">\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           R\
                                     </label>\
                                     <label>\
                                         <input type="checkbox">\
                                            W\
                                     </label>\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           D\
                                     </label>\
                                  </div>\
                               </td>\
                               <td>\
                                  <div class="checkbox">\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           R\
                                     </label>\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           W\
                                     </label>\
                                     <label>\
                                        <input type="checkbox">\
                                           D\
                                     </label>\
                                  </div>\
                               </td>\
                            </tr>';

            var obj =[
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 1",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 1,
                    "RoleName": "Role 1"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 1",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 2,
                    "RoleName": "Role 2"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 1",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
                    "RoleName": "Role 2"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 1,
                    "RoleName": "Role 2"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 2,
                    "RoleName": "Role 2"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
                    "RoleName": "Role 2"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 2",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
                    "RoleName": "Role 3"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 3",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 1,
                    "RoleName": "Role 3"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 3",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 2,
                    "RoleName": "Role 3"
                },
                {
                    "ScreenName": "Screen 3",
                    "PermissiontypeID": 3,
                    "RoleName": "Role 3"
                }
            ];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="perm">
    <tr>
        <th>Permission</th>
        <th>Role 1</th>
        <th>Role 2</th>
        <th>Role 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only one drawback here. It will stop to work if you create a new role